# Return from an iterator and then throw StopIteration

Tags: python, iterator, stopiteration

What would be the nice way to return something from an iterator one last time when it's exhausted. I'm using a flag, but this is rather ugly:

```
class Example():

    def __iter__(self):
        self.lst = [1,2,3]
        self.stop = False # <-- ugly            
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.stop:  # <-- ugly
            raise StopIteration
        if len(self.lst) == 0:
            self.stop = True            
            return "one last time"
        return self.lst.pop()
```

Background: I'm fetching an unknown amount of strings from an external source and send them further down to the caller. When the process is over, I want to emit a string "x records processed". I have no control over calling code, so this must be done inside my iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just yield from `__iter__` which would turn it into a generator function (alternately you could just write a generator function as suggested by Dan). Just as a warning, this might be misleading to people that abuse the `next` method.

```
class Example():

    def __iter__(self):
        lst = [1,2,3]
        for i in reversed(lst):
            yield i
        yield "one last time"
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use a generator function instead:

```
def example():
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    while lst:
        yield lst.pop()
    yield 'one last time'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you can make an object's `__iter__` method be a generator function itself, in cases where you can't or don't want to use a generator directly.

Comment: Thanks, "yield" is what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return one extra thing.  That's a bad idea because it doesn't extend well.  What if you want to do sum as well as count?  Or hash as well as count?  An iterator is a stateful object.  Make use of that.

```
class Example( collections.Iterator ):
    def __iter__(self):
        self.lst = [1,2,3]
        self.count = 0       
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.lst:
            self.count += 1
            return self.lst.pop()
        raise StopIteration()
```

Use it like this.

```
my_iter= iter(Example())
for item in my_iterprin:
    print( item )

print( my_iter.count )
```

Comment: I can't do that because I don't control the calling code (it's a wsgi app).

Comment: I don't control the calling code?  That's rarely true.  Call them on the phone and talk to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Example():
    def __iter__(self):
        self.lst = [1, 2, 3]
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            return self.lst.pop()
        except IndexError:
            print "done iterating"
            raise StopIteration

>>> for i in Example():
...   print i
...
3
2
1
done iterating
```

In your actual code you will probably need to change the exception type that you are catching, but this format should still be applicable.